# Enviar fixeiros de texto pelo smtp em python

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

Exixte alguma forma de enviar fixeiros `.txt` pelo smtplib do python?

Este é o meu codigo atual:

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(Sender, Password_SMTP)
    server.ehlo()
    body = 'Bump request was successful.'
    subject = 'Bump request was successful'

    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, body)

    server.sendmail(Sender, Reciever, message)
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mais ou menos desta mesma forma, usando msg.attach:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
filename = "text.txt"
f = open(filename,'r')
attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)           
msg.attach(attachment)
```

obs: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/

Comment: O que seria esta função `file` na terceira linha?

Comment: Realmente, havia dois problemas na primeira resposta, primeiro eu estava pensando no Python2.7 que usa o read, que foi descontinuado no Python3, que usa o open! Segundo, faltava criar a msg, o que foi corrigido na resposta acima! Desculpas estava usando o smartphone e na pressa esqueci dos detalhes.